# US Embassy in London: Did my H1-B visa get approved or not?

Tags: london, h1b-visas, us-visa

Due to the new policy for the US embassy in London, some visa applicants now can submit their materials without needing to do an interview.
I submitted my application including passport two weeks ago and just got email notice that the materials are being returned by the courier. The online system shows this instead of approval notice:
[image]

Could anyone tell me if it's approved or not?

Thank you!

Comment: If it's (somewhat) similar to applying for a UK passport, it could be them just sending back any "supporting documents" as soon as they've been recorded, independent of any decision. (But I don't know if the US Embassy works that way).

Comment: I doubt the notice means anything other than what it says.

Comment: The question belongs on [Expatriates.SE] but I was the only one of the 5 close voters to vote for that reason, so the notice shows a different reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I checked USCIS and got the news that my visa was refused.
That explains a lot since other people saw the approval message on the visa info website of the US Embassy London.

[image]

Comment: FWIW, the message shown ("long refused") is usually not a definitive refusal, but a "refusal" under 221(g) pending administrative processing ("check"). The AP may lead to an approval or a definitive refusal. This is common if you are from sensitive countries (e.g. China, Iran) or study in sensitive domains (e.g. chemistry, computer science, electronic engineering).